# autoplay list of songs html

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

This is the code I was trying.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
   <source src ="http://www.claudeschneider.com/shared/movements/Modern%20Chilled/Thirteen%20Senses%20-%20Into%20the%20Fire.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
  <source src="http://198.15.68.162/35bRm/music/hindi/seial/star_plus/2013/saraswatichandra/Piya-Re_(webmusic.in).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">    

</source></audio>`
```

But it autoplays the first song, but it does not move to the second song..

How can I make a playlist in html that autoplays?

Please do say what is wrong in the above code.

I am trying this in blogger.
(So please don't suggest .m3u stuff/ because for that I have to upload the .m3u file somewhere and I tried to do that by uploading the .m3u file in dropbox and google drive it doesn't seem to be working...)

Thank you